# How do I host an testnet Electron Cash (Electrum fork) server or where can I find a working one that is online?

Tags: testnet, bitcoin-cash

I have not been able to find any working nodes for Electron Cash in testnet. Does anyone know of an existing node that is up to date and matches the height of a tesnet Bitcoin Cash explorer: https://www.blocktrail.com/tBCC

Thanks!